# Set array size at runtime

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, c99

I know how to create a structure array inside a function:

```
typedef struct item
{
    int test;
};

void func (void) 
{
    int arraysize = 5;
    item ar[arraysize];  
}
```

But how do I to the same when the array is declared globally:

```
typedef struct item 
{
    int test; 
};

item ar[];

void func (void)
{
    int arraysize = 5;
    // What to here?
}
```

Comment: @larsks I knew about malloc() being a solution, but I hoped there was a cleaner method.

Comment: @Joshua What kind of "clearer" solution? `malloc()` is just fine. This is exactly the case it has been invented for.

Comment: When does the array size become known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you like this:

```
typedef struct item 
{
    int test; 
};

item *arr;

void func (void)
{
    int arraysize = 5;
    arr = calloc(arraysize,sizeof(item)); 
     // check if arr!=NULL : allocation fail!
     // do your work 

    free(arr);
}
```

But its dynamic allocation!

And if `arraysize` *known at compilation time*. then better to create a macro like this:

```
#define arraysize  5

typedef struct item 
{
    int test; 
};

item arr[arraysize];
```

<sub>side note using upper case for macro constants is good practice</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Variable length arrays are only allowed in C for arrays with automatic storage duration. Arrays declared at file scope have static storage duration so cannot be variable length arrays.

You can use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory for an array object whose size is unknow at compilation time.

Comment: Would be possible to create the variable array inside the function, and have a global pointer to it, or does the array going out of scope make this impossible?

Comment: @Joshua this has nothing to do with scope but with storage duration. The variable length array can go out of scope it is ok, but you should not exit the function where it is declared. When you exit the function where the array is declared, the object is discarded.

Answer (score 2):

```
item * ar:
int count;

void foo()
{
    count = 5;
    ar = malloc(sizeof(item) * count);
    // check to make sure it is not null...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct item 
{
    int test; 
};

#define ARRAYSIZE 5

item ar[ARRAYSIZE];
```

Comment: That is only possible when 5 is known at compile-time.

Comment: Your **int arraysize = 5;** implies that the size IS known at compile time.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I know the difference. His code has arraysize = 5. That IS compile time.

Comment: @JimRhodes - Perhaps clarity is needed on the question title `Set array size at runtime`...

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the size of an array at run time. You can perform a dynamic memory allocation and call `realloc()` when needed.

**EDIT:** In your case,I suggest do somethig like this:

```
item *ar;

    void func(void)
    {
      int arraysize = 5;
      ar = malloc(arsize);
      if(ar) {
      /* do something */
     }
     //don't forget to free(ar) when no longer needed
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to modify the size of an existing (initialized) array, but to specify the size for an uninitialized array. Or doesnt that make any difference for C?

Comment: @Joshua: Makes no any difference in C. See my edit. `malloc()` is your solution.